# Botão para abrir uma nova activity está voltando para a activity inicial

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Na minha aplicação fiz uma tela de login e coloquei um botão para autenticar o usuário pelo Facebook, depois de logado vem a tela principal e nessa tela tem um botão que chama uma nova Activity. Até ai tudo funcionando bem. Agora o problema, fui colocar um botão na tela de login para autenticar o usuário pelo Google, ele loga e abra a tela principal, a mesma do login com o Facebook, porém quando clico no botão para abrir a nova Activity ao invés de abrir a nova tela está voltando para a tela de login

Código do botão Da MainActivity

```
  Button Config= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Config);
            PerfilButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Config.class));

                }
            });
```

Código para abrir a Activity principal

```
private void goMainScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Esse *goMainScreen()* é usado para chamar a tela principal depois que o usuário logar pelo Google

Ao logar com o Facebook tudo funciona bem, mas ao logar com o Google dá problema ao clicar no botão para abrir a nova Activity.

Acho que o erro pode estar no botão, mas não entendo porque funciona bem ao logar com o Facebook mas não com o Google, se os dois modos de logar abrem a mesma tela

Comment: O problema até pode estar no botão, mas se ele funciona com um e não com o outro, possivelmente, a questão está na integração do login do Google. No primeiro trecho, você declara o botão `Config`, mas define o listener de `PerfilButton`. Talvez tenha que expor mais código pra que fique claro.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim

```
Button Config= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Config);
    PerfilButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Config.class)
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas descobri o problema e não era no botão, era na autenticação do usuário. Ao clicar no botão a nova Activity realiza uma consulta no registro para buscar as informações do usuário, como já estava logado ao realizar a consulta estava duplicando o registro ao dar esse erro o programa voltava para a tela de login. Mais uma vez obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

Olha eu utilizo da seguinte forma quando quero instanciar no adapter :

`

holder.Bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent j = new Intent(v.getContext(),FrmHoras.class);
j.putExtra("CodUsuario",Long.toString(ap.getCodContratado()));
j.putExtra("IdContador",Long.toString(ap.getIdContador()));
((AppCompatActivity)v.getContext()).startActivity(janelaDaLista);
finish();                  }
}
);
`